# SQL statement that selects array values

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am working on a visual basic project. I have a mdb database connected to my project. I want to add a `SELECT` query that finds the results which are in array that i give it on my program

I have tried to write a statement like that:

```
SELECT kodu, adi_soyadi, sectigi_ders_say
FROM ogrenciler
WHERE kodu IN ?
```

But it does not work. In my page codes I have an array and I want to find results from `"ogrenciler"` table where the `"kodu"` is in my array.

Comment: You can't pass an array as a single value like that.  When you use `IN`, you have to have a list of discrete values.  You can build the SQL and use parameters, which is the correct way, like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298).

Comment: Is Kodu a `String` Field or a numeric field? You could build a comma delimited String (in parenthesis) to append to your `IN` statement - `Kodu IN (val1, val2, val3)` etc (include single quotes around each variable if it's a String)

Comment: String field. Its a good way but i dont know how many arguments will be in my array

Comment: You don't need to know how many elements are in the array.  If you weren't going to use parameters then you could do this: `sql = $"SELECT ... WHERE kodu IN ('{String.Join("', '", myArray}')"`.  If you are going to use parameters, which you generally should, then the link I provided uses a loop and thus can handle any number of elements.

Comment: You can load the array into a temporary table and then use an INNER JOIN to get the results you are looking for. I don't think you can have an array parameter and use something like "WHERE kodu IN (?)"

Comment: I just noticed that this question is tagged VBA and VB.NET.  There's no justification for that in the question itself.  You need to construct the SQL and it will be being done in either VB.NET or VBA but not both.  The descriptions for those tags explicitly state that they are different languages so don't spam tags.  If this is actually a VBA question then the principle of what I have said remains but the VB.NET code I have provided is inappropriate so you've wasted my time.  Please remove whichever tag doesn't actually apply to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could send that array  to a temp table in Access, but that would  prevent more then one user using the software at the same time. (or you could add some user name to the temp table. However, if the array of choices is small, say about max 50, then you can create the sql string.

eg:

```
    Dim MySQL As String = "SELECT * from tblHotels WHERE ID IN("
    Dim IdList(5) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        IdList(i) = i
    Next

    Dim MyList As String = ""
    For i = 1 To 5
        If MyList <> "" Then MyList = MyList & ","
        MyList = MyList & IdList(i)
    Next
    MySQL = MySQL & MyList & ")"
    Using MyCon2 As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.OLESQL)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(MySQL, MyCon2)
        Dim rstDat As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(rstDat)
        For i = 0 To rstDat.Rows.Count - 1
            Debug.Print(rstDat.Rows(i).Item("HotelName"))
        Next ' etc etc. etc.
    End Using
```

So you can use the SQL format of:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblHotels where ID IN (1,2,3)
```

And thus build up the "list". The only downside to this approach is that the sql string is limited to 2000 characters. So, if your list is larger then say 50 or so items, then you have to adopt a different approach.